# Remove Blank tags using Regex in PHP

Tags: php, regex

Is it possible to remove all the blank `<a>` tags in some HTML code using regex?

For example,

```
<a href="this-goes-somewhere.com" rel="external"></a>
<a href="go-to-that-page.html"></a>
<a href="this-should-stay.html">This Should Stay</a>
<a href="this-should-stay.html"><img src="kitten.jpg"/></a>
```

In this case, the regex should remove the first two links. I used `<a(.*?)></a>` to achieve this but it matches all four links.

Any help would be appreciated.

I thought `?` was meant to stop at minimum possible number of characters.

UPDATE: The HTML will not be invalid, I am generating it myself. Using Regex will be much easier in this particular case, in my opinion.

Comment: You should *never* parse HTML with regex. Use [a PHP DOM parser](http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/) instead.

Comment: @JayBlanchard I am very certain that the HTML will not be invalid. I am generating it myself. Using `Regex` would be easy in this case. :)

Comment: Really? Because you've found it not to be easy ;-)

Comment: Haha. That was clever @JayBlanchard . I meant to say that it will just be one line.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I modified your regex so that it would only match the first two links by changing `.*` to `[^<]`: https://regex101.com/r/nhu2T7/2

This PHP code will run that regex and print out the result:

```
<?php

$re = '/(<a[^<]*?><\/a>)/m';
$str = '<a href="this-goes-somewhere.com" rel="external"></a>
<a href="go-to-that-page.html"></a>
<a href="this-should-stay.html">This Should Stay</a>
<a href="this-should-stay.html"><img src="kitten.jpg"/></a>';

echo preg_replace($re, '', $str);
```

Result:

```
<a href="this-should-stay.html">This Should Stay</a>
<a href="this-should-stay.html"><img src="kitten.jpg"/></a>
```

Execute at: http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/dd2b986b80ac6a2c7fd173f65070dd2ce1d78d3c

Comment: Thanks Zach. What did the `[^<]` part do? :)

Comment: Selects all characters in the group (`[...]`) that are not (`^`) left angle brackets (`<`). So, it will match until it reaches the start of another element. This lets the edge case you have with the `<img>` tag work.

Comment: Check the regex101 link I included, it explains the query on that page very nicely

Comment: Just one more question Zach. I always thought that `?` tries to stop matching as soon as possible. Shouldn't it have stopped at the first `>` in all four links?

Comment: `?` means "may or may not exist". So the regex string "`^Hell?o$`" would match "Hello" and "Helo"

Comment: It is a little confusing. :) Shouldn't `(.*?)>` mean match as few characters as possible and stop as soon as you see `>`? Your explanation for this `regex` pattern will definitely help me a lot in future.